Ok to truncate ADMINNOTIFICATION_INBOX?
I migrated from M1 a few months ago and I've checked the M2 DB today and noticed that the table: ADMINNOTIFICATION_INBOX is pretty big with messages from years and years ago, must have been migrated from my M1.
I'm on M2 2.4.6 now, is it possible to just truncate the table?
When I go the admin notifications page in the backend, it doesn't show any of the really old notifications in the front end, so I can't delete it from the front end.
Thank you.

YES, it's totally safe to remove those notification form table and you can directly truncate table.
If you see structure of table, It is no where related to other table!
And above All, I just truncated on localhost and can't seen any issue.
